# Two buttons in a RecyclerView row conflicting

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a Recycler View that constains rows with an TextView and two Buttons. The buttons work as up/downvotes and can only be clicked once at a time. If one of the buttons is clicked, the other one cannot be clicked if the previous was not "unclicked". The TextView represents the score.

The problem I'm having is that the the text in the TextView is being handled correctly, increasing only when it is possible, however, the background color of the row is always wrong and does not follow the rule.
I am using SQLite as a table for checking if the post was up/downvoted and setting "null" when none of the buttons is clicked.

The following code is written in the MainActivity.java.

```
   scoreAdapter.setOnButtonDownClickListener(new ScoreAdapter.onButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onButtonClick(View parent, Button btn, int position) {
            int postId = (int) parent.getTag();
            String vote = databaseHandler.getVote(postId);
            if(vote.equals("down")){
                scoreAdapter.setScore(position,Integer.parseInt(scoreAdapter.getScore(position)) + 1);
                databaseHandler.writeVote((int) parent.getTag(),"null");
                parent.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notVoted,getApplication().getTheme()));
                scoreAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
            }else if(! vote.equals("up")){
                scoreAdapter.setScore(position,Integer.parseInt(scoreAdapter.getScore(position)) - 1);
                databaseHandler.writeVote((int) parent.getTag(),"down");
                parent.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.downVoted,getApplication().getTheme()));
                scoreAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
            Log.i(parent.getTag().toString(),databaseHandler.getVote((int) parent.getTag()));
        }
    });

    scoreAdapter.setOnButtonUpClickListener(new ScoreAdapter.onButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onButtonClick(View parent, Button btn, int position) {
            int postId = (int) parent.getTag();
            String vote = databaseHandler.getVote(postId);
            if(vote.equals("up")){
                scoreAdapter.setScore(position,Integer.parseInt(scoreAdapter.getScore(position)) - 1);
                databaseHandler.writeVote((int) parent.getTag(),"null");
                parent.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notVoted,getApplication().getTheme()));
                scoreAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
            }else if(! vote.equals("down")){
                scoreAdapter.setScore(position,Integer.parseInt(scoreAdapter.getScore(position)) + 1);
                databaseHandler.writeVote((int) parent.getTag(),"up");
                parent.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.upVoted,getApplication().getTheme()));
                scoreAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
            Log.i(parent.getTag().toString(),databaseHandler.getVote((int) parent.getTag()));
        }
    });
```

ScoreAdapter is the RecyclerView adapter. I know the interfaces used for the onClick Event should be correct because the TextView modification is correct. The following code is the code inside the ViewHolder class.

```
public interface onButtonClickListener{
    void onButtonClick(View parent, Button btn, int position);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public TextView score;
    public Button buttonUp;
    public Button buttonDown;

    public ViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        score = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textScore);
        buttonUp = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUp);
        buttonDown = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnDown);

        buttonDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("Down","clicked");
                if(onButtonDownClickListener != null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        onButtonDownClickListener.onButtonClick(itemView, buttonDown, position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        buttonUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("Up","clicked");
                if(onButtonUpClickListener != null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        onButtonUpClickListener.onButtonClick(itemView, buttonUp, position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

How can I fix the background color change? Is it possible that by clicking one of the buttons, the other one also receives the click?

EDIT:

MainAcitivty.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    ArrayList<Score> scores = new ArrayList<>();
    scores.add(new Score(2,0));
    scores.add(new Score(0,1));
    scores.add(new Score(-1,2));
    scores.add(new Score(3,3));
    scores.add(new Score(10,4));
    scores.add(new Score(50,5));
    scores.add(new Score(62,6));
    scores.add(new Score(8,7));
    scores.add(new Score(-5,8));
    scores.add(new Score(12,10));
    scores.add(new Score(26,11));
    scores.add(new Score(32,12));
    scores.add(new Score(9,13));
    scores.add(new Score(95,14));
    final LocalDatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new LocalDatabaseHandler(this);

    final ScoreAdapter scoreAdapter = new ScoreAdapter(this,scores);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(scoreAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    scoreAdapter.setOnButtonDownClickListener(new ScoreAdapter.onButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onButtonClick(View parent, Button btn, int position) {
            int postId = (int) parent.getTag();
            String vote = databaseHandler.getVote(postId);
            if(vote.equals("down")){

                scoreAdapter.setScore(position,Integer.parseInt(scoreAdapter.getScore(position)) + 1);
                databaseHandler.writeVote((int) parent.getTag(),"null");
                btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notVoted));

            }else if(! vote.equals("up")){

                scoreAdapter.setScore(position,Integer.parseInt(scoreAdapter.getScore(position)) - 1);
                databaseHandler.writeVote((int) parent.getTag(),"down");
                btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.downVoted));

            }
        }
    });

    scoreAdapter.setOnButtonUpClickListener(new ScoreAdapter.onButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onButtonClick(View parent, Button btn, int position) {
            int postId = (int) parent.getTag();
            String vote = databaseHandler.getVote(postId);
            if(vote.equals("up")){

                scoreAdapter.setScore(position,Integer.parseInt(scoreAdapter.getScore(position)) - 1);
                databaseHandler.writeVote((int) parent.getTag(),"null");
                btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notVoted));

            }else if(! vote.equals("down")){

                scoreAdapter.setScore(position,Integer.parseInt(scoreAdapter.getScore(position)) + 1);
                databaseHandler.writeVote((int) parent.getTag(),"up");
                btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.upVoted));

            }
        }
    });

    scoreAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new ScoreAdapter.onItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Integer.toString((int) view.getTag()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
}
```

}

ScoreAdapter.java

```
public class ScoreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScoreAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public interface onItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

public interface onButtonClickListener{
    void onButtonClick(View parent, Button btn, int position);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView score;
    Button buttonUp;
    Button buttonDown;
    View parent;

    public ViewHolder(View v){
        super(v);
        score = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textScore);
        buttonUp = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUp);
        buttonDown = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnDown);
        parent = v;

        buttonDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("Down","clicked");
                if(onButtonDownClickListener != null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        onButtonDownClickListener.onButtonClick(parent, buttonDown, position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        buttonUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("Up","clicked");
                if(onButtonUpClickListener != null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        onButtonUpClickListener.onButtonClick(parent, buttonUp, position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("View","clicked");
                if(onItemClickListener != null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        onItemClickListener.onItemClick(parent,position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

private List<Score> scoreList;
private Context context;
private onItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
public onButtonClickListener onButtonUpClickListener;
public onButtonClickListener onButtonDownClickListener;

public ScoreAdapter(Context context,List<Score> scores){
    this.scoreList = scores;
    this.context = context;
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(ScoreAdapter.onItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

public void setOnButtonUpClickListener(onButtonClickListener onButtonUpClickListener) {
    this.onButtonUpClickListener = onButtonUpClickListener;
}

public void setOnButtonDownClickListener(onButtonClickListener onButtonDownClickListener) {
    this.onButtonDownClickListener = onButtonDownClickListener;
}

public List<Score> getScoreList() {
    return scoreList;
}

public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public ScoreAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    View scoreView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.data_layout,parent,false);
    return new ScoreAdapter.ViewHolder(scoreView);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(ScoreAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position){
    Score s = scoreList.get(position);
    viewHolder.parent.setTag(s.getId());
    viewHolder.score.setText(s.getScore());
}

public int getItemCount(){
    return scoreList.size();
}

public String getScore(int position){
    return getScoreList().get(position).getScore();
}

public void setScore(int position,int score){
    getScoreList().get(position).setScore(Integer.toString(score));
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong. As I know, `down` is the antonyms of `up`

```
// Your vote is down
    if(vote.equals("down")){
        scoreAdapter.setScore(position,Integer.parseInt(scoreAdapter.getScore(position)) + 1);
        databaseHandler.writeVote((int) parent.getTag(),"null");
        parent.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notVoted,getApplication().getTheme()));
        scoreAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
// Your vote is still down (Or some thing that just not equal to "up")
    }else if(! vote.equals("up")){
        scoreAdapter.setScore(position,Integer.parseInt(scoreAdapter.getScore(position)) - 1);
        databaseHandler.writeVote((int) parent.getTag(),"down");
        parent.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.downVoted,getApplication().getTheme()));
        scoreAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
```

Just use simple `if/else` condition

Comment: There are 4 options: none (the initial), null (the one I set when it's not upvoted nor downvoted), up and down. If it is down, I want to set it to null (first condition). If it is none or null, I want to set it to down (second condition). I don't see the error.

Comment: but If it isn't up, may be it's down?

Comment: But if it's down, wouldn't it enter the first condition? Since I have else, it wouldn't access the second part.

Comment: When it's down, it goes to first condition and never care the condition in else if. Try it

Answer (score 0):

```
/* your first ClickListener for the Button */  
  scoreAdapter.setOnButtonDownClickListener(new ScoreAdapter.onButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onButtonClick(View parent, Button btn, int position) {
                int postId = (int) parent.getTag();
                String vote = databaseHandler.getVote(postId);
                if(vote.equals("down")){

                    scoreAdapter.setScore(position,Integer.parseInt(scoreAdapter.getScore(position)) + 1);
                    databaseHandler.writeVote((int) parent.getTag(),"null");
                    btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notVoted));

                }else if(! vote.equals("up")){

                    scoreAdapter.setScore(position,Integer.parseInt(scoreAdapter.getScore(position)) - 1);
                    databaseHandler.writeVote((int) parent.getTag(),"down");
                    btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.downVoted));

                }
            }
        });
```

/* your second ClickListener for the Button again.*/

/* Here is a problem you set up two time button click listener, so you have to click twice in order to make it work */

**you don't need setOnClickListener() -- the below code -- inside ScoreAdapter class**

```
buttonDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("Down","clicked");
                if(onButtonDownClickListener != null){
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if(position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                        onButtonDownClickListener.onButtonClick(itemView, buttonDown, position);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The first code piece is in the MainActivity. I don't actually want to change the whole RecyclerView's color, but only the row's.

Comment: @GabrielLima Did you try my code? Does this change the color of whole RecyclerView? If it does then you are about to solve this. You just need to fix the reference.

Comment: It did change the RecyclerView, the problem is probably with the reference of the row.

Comment: @GabrielLima please use recyclerView.getChildAt(getAdapterPosition()). It will solve your problem

Comment: I agree it should, but it didn't.

Comment: public static View myView; public ViewHolder(View v){ View myView = v;  } /* now you can do myView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notVoted,getApplication().getTheme())); */

Comment: I am trying by using the static atribute, by sending the button and changing the button's BG color, but still it does not work. When I decide to change the recyclerView's BG color, it works, but not with the Row or the button. It kind of stays the opposite.

Comment: But not exactly. If I just change the position, sometimes both get colored.

Comment: static ViewHolder holder;
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) { //I created the viewholder for my custom row

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_for_whatsgoingon_adapter, viewGroup, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return holder;

    } /* Now, you can use recyclerView.getChildAt(holder.getAdapterPosition()); *

Comment: @GabrielLima, I modified my answer, It should solve your problem man. Just correct on the reference. I don't have AndroidStudio here, otherwise, I would love to solve your problem man. I am just trying it searching docs.

Comment: @GabrielLima, send me your whole code in infofuniversities@gmail.com

Comment: Sent the email.

Comment: @GabrielLima, you said, you want to change the color of the button? Then it is easy man. buttonUp.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notVoted,getApplication().getTheme()));

Comment: The same problem happens. If I change the view's color or the buttons colors, the result is the same.

Comment: @GabrielLima, You can do recyclerView.getChildAt(holder.getUpButton().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.notVoted,getApplication().getTheme())); /* note holder should be correctly referenced */

Comment: But if I don't set that inside the ScoreAdapter, I don't have a real listener for an onClick event. The onButtonDownClickListener.onButtonClick(itemView, buttonDown, position) is just an interface in order to get the data inside the MainAcitvity.

Comment: @You have not done the implementation but you completed the setuping listener in MainActivity. You setup listener, now it is ready to listen your mouse click. But again in ScoreAdapter you setup another listener for the same button, it further listens (expects) mouse click, That's why you have to click twice. And this is your problem.

Comment: I am just trying to understand my error. In the MainActivity am I setting a listener? Because what I am actually doing is just setting an ScoreAdapter atribute with a Setter method. However since this atribute is from an Interface (which does not extend anything), I need to implement it in the Main Activity. So, I am setting the listener in the ScoreAdapter class and just accessing it in the MainActivity.

Comment: public void onButtonClick is not the onClick method, it is a method I created without any previous implementation.